# To lend spice to our frozen staples?

Tags: meaning

Would anybody please help me understanding the following sentence?

> On what do you think those choicely flavored yeast cakes that we eat to lend spice to our frozen staples grow?

It was taken from Foundation and Earth, Asimov. I didn't catch the meaning.

Comment: Does it help to know that, according to Merriam-Webster, one definition of _staple_ is "a commodity for which the demand is constant"? Basic foods, such as simple grains, that people depend on for subsistence are often referred to as "staples."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is regarding **yeast cakes** that are eaten for the purpose of **lending spice** (i.e. adding flavor) to **frozen staples**.

In particular, it's asking **on what** (e.g. surface, substrate, nutrients) these yeast cakes grow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The trick was on frozen staples. I had never heard this before and was thinking about the iron object we use to attach sheets of paper.